# Infobright Community Edition

Tags: mysql, database, infobright

Is there any way how to access a table in the format used from the infobright community edition (basically a folder with multiple .frm files and subfolders with .ctb files)? The infobright community edition software is not anymore freely available...

Answer (score 0):

https://infobright.com/blog/the-final-frontiers-of-ice/ says:

> "Infobright will store all ICE versions internally.  If you would like
>   access to a particular ICE build, please contact us."
>   (https://infobright.com/about/contact-us/)

Comment: thanks for the reply! I already contacted infobright yesterday. I was just keen if there is any other solution since I'm in a situation where I need urgent access